# linking graphviz to qt

Tags: qt, graphviz

I've been tried to run this program for 3 days but it does not work ...any help pls

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = QGraphViz
TEMPLATE = app
#Configure GraphViz path here :
GRAPHVIZ_PATH = D:/Graphviz2.38
#GraphViz librairie
DEFINES += WIN32_DLL
DEFINES += GVDLL
DEFINES += WITH_CGRAPH
INCLUDEPATH += $$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/include/graphviz
LIBS += -L$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib -lgvc -lcgraph -lgraph -lcdt

SOURCES += main.cpp\
MainWindow.cpp \
QGVScene.cpp \
QGraphicsViewEc.cpp \
QGVNode.cpp \
QGVEdge.cpp \
QGVSubGraph.cpp \
QGVCore.cpp

HEADERS += MainWindow.h \
QGVScene.h \
QGraphicsViewEc.h \
QGVNode.h \
QGVEdge.h \
QGVSubGraph.h \
QGVCore.h
FORMS += MainWindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
ress.qrc
```

error massege is:

> QGVScene.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol agset
>   referenced    in function "public: void __cdecl
>   QGVScene::setRootNode(class QGVNode *)"
>   (?setRootNode@QGVScene@@QEAAXPEAVQGVNode@@@Z)

what's wrong in this .pro file

any help?

Comment: Does it work if you add PRE_TARGETDEPS+=$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib/libname.lib ?

Comment: how shall i use it?delete )LIBS += -L$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib -lgvc -lcgraph -lgraph -lcdt) and then use it or...?

Comment: i use it PRE_TARGETDEPS+=$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib/-lgvc -lcgraph -lgraph -lcdt   but  igot this error :-1: error: dependent 'D:\Graphviz2.38\lib\release\lib\-lgvc' does not exist.   i'm sure the path is correct

Comment: No. You should point to the graphviz.lib file: PRE_TARGETDEPS+=$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib/GRAPHVIZ.lib

Comment: Without the -lgvc ... Stuff

Comment: i tried it in smaller project and  did all the things you sayd but it does not work (PRE_TARGETDEPS+=$$GRAPHVIZ_PATH/lib/release/lib) but ...main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol agopen referenced in function main   did i do somthing wrong again?

Comment: No, the path you specify is a .lib file. Dont you have a graphviz.lib file in the folder?

Comment: no i dont have graphviz.lib